# Combining results from two requests based on data entered in two search fields

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am building a search form in angular which will autocomplete the results either by name or by city.

I am able to get the result for a single input field. I am not able to merge name and city search results into one.

```js
 this.SearchResult = this.nameField.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      filter(data => data.length > 3),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(v => !!v),
      switchMap((name) => {
        return this.http.get<any>(
          environment.api_services.search.url + `/api/name/andy`).pipe(
          map(res => res.data)
        );
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forkJoin` :

```js
this.SearchResult = this.nameField.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      filter(data => data.length > 3),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(v => !!v),
      switchMap((name) => forkJoin(this.http.get<any>(
          environment.api_services.search.url + `/api/name/andy`).pipe(
          map(res => res.data)
        ), this.http.get<any>(
          environment.api_services.search.url + `/api/city/andy`).pipe(
          map(res => res.data)
        )){

      })
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. I have two html inputs one is "nameField" and one is "city field".  If I enter the value in nameField I want to do get results by the name and if I enter a value in city field I need to get results from by city. If I enter in both I need to merge and get the data. Because I am piping on nameField I am not sure how to get the input field data from "city field"

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] of your issue if you want an answer suited to your issue.